# Laravel Mix "Unrecognised input" in Vue components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, webpack-style-loader, less-loader

After upgrade webpack from verstion 3 to 5 I get error with inline load styles.

```
✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 2.29s

ERROR in ./app/Admin/assets/partials/bootstrapForm/ImageSelector.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=833cd440&scoped=true&lang=less& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-17[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-17[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./app/Admin/assets/partials/bootstrapForm/ImageSelector.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=833cd440&scoped=true&lang=less&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


import api from "!../../../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
              ^
Unrecognised input
      Error in /workspace/app/Admin/assets/partials/bootstrapForm/ImageSelector.vue (line 1, column 16)

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

If remove LESS LOADER:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
...
```

the problem is lost, but css inline will not be added to page.
Here is small partion of package.json

```
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "webpack": "^5.25.0"
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
```

Component code ImageSelector.vue:

```
<style scoped lang="less">
    .image-selector {
        input[type=file] {
            display: none;
        }
        img {
            max-height: 200px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Have any ideas?